# Intercept/Disable keyboard shortcuts (ex. CMD+q)

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there anyway to intercept and change/ignore, globally, a given shortcut in Objective-C for a Mac application?

An example is BetterTouchTool, it can override any shortcut you provide.

What I want to do is prevent the 'quit' shortcut (i.e. <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) when a specific application is open (because in this instance the shortcut is inadvertantly pressed and closes the application undesirably for some people).

In short, can I listen for any global key events and then change the event *before* it gets delivered to its intended application?

Comment: As an entirely non-programming solution, you can just change the key equivalent for that one application in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts > [the specific app] (I think this has moved in Mavericks, but it should still be in System Preferences somewhere.) I have my browser's Quit menu item set to ^⌥⌘Q, for example. Coding-wise, you're looking for CGEventTaps.

Comment: This does not work, as the application is launched using a bash script and is not a *.app application. I will look into CGEventTaps, do you have any immediated resources for that?

Comment: Gotcha. The [Quartz Event Services reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) is the official doc.

Comment: This works for macos/pynput: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482840/how-to-suppress-function-keys-in-macos-quartz-pynput/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to setup the event listener

```
CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap,
                                kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                                kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
                                CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown),
                                &KeyDownCallback,
                                NULL);

CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, eventTap, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CFRelease(runLoopSource);
CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
```

And then here is the "callback":

```
static CGEventRef KeyDownCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy,
                              CGEventType type,
                              CGEventRef event,
                              void *refcon)
{
    /* Do something with the event */
    NSEvent *e = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:event];
    return event;
}
```

on the parsed NSEvent, there are the `modifierFlags` and `keyCode` properties. `keyCode` is the code of the key that was pressed, and `modifierFlags` is the different modifiers that were pressed (Shift, Alt/Option, Command, etc).

Simply `return NULL;` in the `KeyDownCallback` method to stop the event from propogating.

Note: there seems to be an issue with the event tap timing out, to solve this problem you can 'reset' the event tap.

In the `KeyDownCallback` method, check if the `CGEventType type` is `kCGEventTapDisabledByTimeout` like so:

```
if (type == kCGEventTapDisabledByTimeout)
{
    /* Reset eventTap */
    return NULL;
}
```

and where `Reset eventTap` is, execute the setup of the event listener above again.